# ajax jquery not working with bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

i am trying to convert my existing site with bootstrap but unfortulaty my old ajax code is notworking with bootstrap i have to add latest jquery file to run my ajax but in both conditions it is not working is there any solutions

Comment: yes problem is bootstrap not working with my normal ajax/jquery code

Comment: It must rely on something else. I Use jquery ajax along bootstrap with no problems what so ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am assuming that you have used `$.post(...)` for your requests. You should visit [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) for post. there you can find many depreciation notes within the text.

But to really help you, and not just giving hints, you should upload some code.

Comment: if a simply use following code with jquery library $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: url,
data: data,
success: success,
dataType: dataType
}); bootstrap and normal ajax stop working

Comment: that's really strange. Because i have no problems with bootstrap and jQuery ajax requests. it would be great to know why your requests fail.

Comment: @Jabeen, `$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: url, data: data, success: success, dataType: dataType })` that looks wrong, what is `success: success` ??

Comment: @Jabeen Show example of your `$.ajax` usage in your site that is not working.

Comment: $('.test').live('mouseover',function() { for this line it shows error that "live" unknown

Comment: not only ajax but my other code is not working if i include bootstrap

Comment: @Jabeen You should replace all your `.live()` calls with [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) ones.

Comment: `live` has been depreciated. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/live/) for workaround. You can use `$(document).on("mouseover", ".test", function(){...});`

Comment: thanks $("input[type=radio]").change(function(){ this function is also not working

Comment: $(document).ready(function() { this line also appear in errors ReferenceError: $ is not defined
[Break On This Error]  

$(document).ready(function() {

Comment: You have obviosly not included jquery OR you run the code BEFORE jquery is included (if you have used a bootstrap template, js is typically included at the end of index.html

Comment: try to replace `$("input[type=radio]").change(function(){...});` by `$('input:radio').on('change', function(){....});`

Answer (score -1):

Try to use a debugger to see what is going on, I have the same issue where my Bootstrap modal was not showing from a javascript call, because of AJAX is overwriting the other JQuery javascript. So far I have found no solution for this...